# Is there a way to use class inside html style tag

Tags: html, css

I need to override theme style in a very specific place.
I don't want to rewrite the theme.

Is there a way to use class and  id name ins style tag in html body, like this?

```
<div dir="ltr" style=".wp_the_content ul li:before {left: 0 !important;right: auto !important;transform: rotate(180deg) !important;}">
```

Comment: no, the style attribute inside an element allows to only define the style to the element itself

Comment: Why don't you create that css rule in a custom css file, or in a `<style>` tag in your html and then just set the class in its appropiate `class` attribute ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can use `<style>.wp_the_content ul li:before {left: 0 !important;right: auto !important;transform: rotate(180deg) !important;}</style>`, but I don't recommend it because it's hard to maintain the project with those internal stylesheets.

Comment: I just need to override this setting for one post.

Comment: @matisa than you should add some class to the post and set those css attributes to this class...

Comment: You all are right. 
The thing is that it's a multi site with a bit complex code. Altering it will mean hours of QA.  Hoped there's a hack that can let me override just one div. I need it for one post.

Comment: @Quentin you have marked my question as duplicate. Can you reference the original? I did not find such a hing.

Comment: @matisa — Look at the big yellow box at the top of the page. (Or the first word of fcalderan's comment which sums it up neatly).

Comment: @Quentin just saw it.  Tnx. 
Didn't show when I wrote the comment. Should I delete this Q?